How to make Latex listen from stdin, but disable interactive mode?
For a project, I want to automatically generate PDFs using Latex. The program should open a latex process (I'm using lualatex) and then write the latex code to stdin.
My problem is now, whenever lualatex encounters an error, it displays the error and then waits for a user input. This leads to my program waiting forever, whenever there's an error in the latex code. Instead, I'd like lualatex to quit whenever encountering an error.
I found that you can tell lualatex to do this by passing --interaction=nonstopmode or --interaction=batchmode, but when I do this, lualatex won't accept input from stdin anymore, as it now needs to read the whole latex code in one go. For example, if I run lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode and then type \documentclass{article} and hit enter, lualatex will immediately stop.
So is there any way I can tell lualatex to stop after en error occured, while still being able to send the latex code part by part?
